# Suppose that $P(A) = \frac{1}{2}$ and $P(B)=\frac{1}{4}$. What can we say for sure about $P(A∪B)?$

Tags: probability

Assume nothing else about $A$ and $B$ except that they are events in some sample space $(S, P)$.

$P(A \cup B) = \frac{1}{8}.$

$P(A \cup B) = \frac{3}{4}.$

$P(A \cup B) \le \frac{3}{4}.$

$P(A \cup B) \ge \frac{1}{2}.$

I know for sure that the third option is true. I know that option 2 is not true, because we can't assume anything specific about A and B being mutually exclusive.

What about the other two?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$P(A\cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A\cap B).$$

So, how is $P(A\cup B)$ related to $P(A) + P(B)$ ? Also:

$$ A\subseteq A\cup B .$$
What does this imply for the probabilities?

Comment: Since $A$ is a subet of $A \cup B$, $P(A \cup B)$ has to have at least the probability of $A$, $P(A)$?

Comment: @dewick49 : Yes.

Answer (score 1):

Another hint: $$P(A\cup B) \ge P(A).$$

Comment: So we have that the third and last option are true. Can you explain why this one is true? Is thanasissdr's hint an explanation? EDIT: Yes, it is - I've answered my own question. :)

Comment: Yes. He copied my "other hint".

Comment: @dewick49 The probability measure is **monotonic**: if $X \subseteq Y$ then $P(X) \leq P(Y)$. Now take $X = A$ and $Y = A \cup B$.

Comment: @CarlHeckman Sorry about that! I was editing my answer before seeing yours (upvoted)!